# Building GStreamer with CMake causes SDP & WebRTC unresolved external symbol errors

Tags: c++, cmake, gstreamer, glib

I'm building a C++ GStreamer project with CMake which depends on GStreamer, GLIB, Libsoup and json-glib. I'm new to CMake and having trouble setting up my project. I've managed to include many of the dependencies but some seem to remain unresolved even though they are part of GStreamer. All GStreamer methods and types are resolved with the exception of SDP and WebRTC. They are, to my understanding, part of GStreamer and are also located inside of the directory which GMake correctly "finds".

These are the errors that are occurring when trying to build the project.

```
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_sdp_message_new referenced in function "void __cdecl soup_websocket_message_cb(struct _SoupWebsocketConnection *,enum SoupWebsocketDataType,struct _GBytes *,void *)" (?soup_websocket_message_cb@@YAXPEAU_SoupWebsocketConnection@@W4SoupWebsocketDataType@@PEAU_GBytes@@PEAX@Z)
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_sdp_message_parse_buffer referenced in function "void __cdecl soup_websocket_message_cb(struct _SoupWebsocketConnection *,enum SoupWebsocketDataType,struct _GBytes *,void *)" (?soup_websocket_message_cb@@YAXPEAU_SoupWebsocketConnection@@W4SoupWebsocketDataType@@PEAU_GBytes@@PEAX@Z)
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_sdp_message_as_text referenced in function "void __cdecl on_offer_created_cb(struct _GstPromise *,void *)" (?on_offer_created_cb@@YAXPEAU_GstPromise@@PEAX@Z)
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_webrtc_session_description_get_type referenced in function "void __cdecl on_offer_created_cb(struct _GstPromise *,void *)" (?on_offer_created_cb@@YAXPEAU_GstPromise@@PEAX@Z)
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_webrtc_session_description_new referenced in function "void __cdecl soup_websocket_message_cb(struct _SoupWebsocketConnection *,enum SoupWebsocketDataType,struct _GBytes *,void *)" (?soup_websocket_message_cb@@YAXPEAU_SoupWebsocketConnection@@W4SoupWebsocketDataType@@PEAU_GBytes@@PEAX@Z)
[build] error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_gst_webrtc_session_description_free referenced in function "void __cdecl on_offer_created_cb(struct _GstPromise *,void *)" (?on_offer_created_cb@@YAXPEAU_GstPromise@@PEAX@Z)
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt`

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for stream-project, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project (stream-project LANGUAGES CXX)

# Packages
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp" "main.h")

# Search all modules that we so desire to use and "include_directories"
pkg_search_module(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-sdp-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gstreamer-app-1.0 gstreamer-webrtc-1.0)
pkg_search_module(GLIB REQUIRED glib-2.0)
pkg_search_module(LIBSOUP REQUIRED libsoup-2.4)
pkg_search_module(JSONGLIB REQUIRED json-glib-1.0)

include_directories(
    ${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${LIBSOUP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    ${JSONGLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

# Link target directories and libraries
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${GST_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${GLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${LIBSOUP_LIBRARY_DIRS}
    ${JSONGLIB_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    ${GST_LIBRARIES}
    ${GLIB_LIBRARIES}
    ${LIBSOUP_LIBRARIES}
    ${JSONGLIB_LIBRARIES}
)

message(STATUS ${GST_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: You may tell if all modules were installed through a package system checking dependencies or installed by hand. In latter case you may have to enable pkg-config install of your custom build(s). Use something like `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-sdp-1.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve it by using a premade find script I found online.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/Webkit/+/master/Source/cmake/FindGStreamer.cmake

It creates all necessary defines which I then include and link.

These are the defaults as specified in the FindGStreamer.cmake file

```
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_APP gstreamer-app-1.0 gst/app/gstappsink.h gstapp-1.0)
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_AUDIO gstreamer-audio-1.0 gst/audio/audio.h gstaudio-1.0)
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_FFT gstreamer-fft-1.0 gst/fft/gstfft.h gstfft-1.0)
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_PBUTILS gstreamer-pbutils-1.0 gst/pbutils/pbutils.h gstpbutils-1.0)
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_VIDEO gstreamer-video-1.0 gst/video/video.h gstvideo-1.0)
```

I extended those above with:

```
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_SDP gstreamer-sdp-1.0 gst/sdp/sdp.h gstsdp-1.0)
FIND_GSTREAMER_COMPONENT(GSTREAMER_WEBRTC gstreamer-webrtc-1.0 gst/webrtc/webrtc.h gstwebrtc-1.0)
```